# multi PHP arrays with same keys and different values to CSV file and special characters

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I have many arrays that share the same keys but in different values, and different order:

```
$array = array(
          'English' => array(
                             '1' => 'Apples',
                             '2' => 'Oranges',
                             '3' => 'Bananas'
                            ),
           'Spanish' => array(
                             '3' => 'Plátanos',
                             '1' => 'Manzanas',
                             '2' => 'Naranjas'
                            ),
            'German' => array(
                             '1' => 'Äpfel',
                             '3' => 'Bananen',
                             '2' => 'Orangen'
                            ),
              );
```

and I want to make a CSV file out of the arrays expecting each array values to be listed in a column next to the value from other arrays that have the same key like in the image:

[image]

I tried this:

```
 $header = array(
        'Key', 'English', 'Spanish', 'German'
    );

  $f_name = 'lang.csv';
  header("Content-type: text/csv");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$f_name");
  $output = fopen("php://output" , "w");
  fputcsv($output, $header);
  
  foreach($array as $row){
      fputcsv($output , array_values( $row ));
  }
  fclose($output);
```

but the results are like in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your inner arrays out of order the obvious thing is to sort by the numeric key. Try [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) in your loop:

```
...
ksort($row);
fputcsv($output , array_values( $row ));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to fputcsv of a $row which holds only 3 values and you want 4 values a key and the others...

First thing first: use UTF-8 for these character encoding and your text should be fine -- meaning your php file encoding should be UTF-8.

As nitrin0 pointed out a good thing would be to ksort($row); but you want to add a fourth value to the $row which holds only 3 values , we add the key even with a ++$c also the array_values is redundant here.

Example:

```
<?php

$array = array(
          'English' => array(
                             '1' => 'Apples',
                             '2' => 'Oranges',
                             '3' => 'Bananas'
                            ),
           'Spanish' => array(
                             '3' => 'Plátanos',
                             '1' => 'Manzanas',
                             '2' => 'Naranjas'
                            ),
            'German' => array(
                             '1' => 'Äpfel',
                             '3' => 'Bananen',
                             '2' => 'Orangen'
                            ),
              );

$header = array(
    'Key', 'English', 'Spanish', 'German'
);

$output = fopen("php://output" , "w");
fputcsv($output, $header);
$c = 1;
foreach($array as $row){
    $row[0] = $c;
    ksort($row);
    ++$c;
    fputcsv($output , $row);
}
fclose($output);
```

will output:

```
Key,English,Spanish,German
1,Apples,Oranges,Bananas
2,Manzanas,Naranjas,Plátanos
3,Äpfel,Orangen,Bananen
```

This solution relies heavily on the fact that in your $array array you had no 0 keys for the fruits...

so instead you can work without relying on 0 keys not existing and stuff without ksort but with merge:

```
$c = 1; 
foreach($array as $row){
    $arr[] = $c;
    $arr = array_merge($arr,$row);
    //print_r($arr);
    //ksort($row);
    ++$c;
    //print_r($row);
    fputcsv($output , $arr);
    $arr = [];
}
fclose($output);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

Will output the same output as the other code example.